# Using Reduce output when multiple variables are identical

Tags: equation-solving

Sometimes Reduce produces output where multiple variables are all assigned to each-other for example:

```
a == b && a == d
```

How can I assign this correctly to a new expression? For example

```
a*b - a*d /. ToRules[a == b && a == d]
(*b^2 - b d*)
```

Should be 0

A Longer example

```
Simplify[{a*b - a*d, a*b*d, r*s*w + b*s}, Assumptions -> {w == 0 & a == b && a == d}]
(*{(b - d) d, a b d, s (b + r w)}*)
```

Comment: Could you use `Simplify[a b - a d, Assumptions -> a == b && a == d]`?
​

Comment: This works. It is much slower on longer equations vs. replacing

Comment: It looks like you want to `ReplaceAll` $b$ and $d$ with $a$, like this `a*b - a*d /. (Reverse /@ ToRules[a == b && a == d])`.

Comment: Simplify with assumptions doesn't work on this longer example: ```Simplify[{a*b - a*d, a*b*d, r*s*w + b*s}, 
 Assumptions -> {w == 0 & a == b && a == d}]``` Outputs: ```(*{(b - d) d, a b d, s (b + r w)}*)``` Additionally If I have a list of equations, how can I ensure that when simplifying with assumptions each equation gets put in terms of the same variables?

Comment: a typo in the second example: `w == 0 &` should be `w == 0 &&`

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[y == a*b - a*d && a == b && a == d, y]
```

> b == d && a == d && y == 0

```
ToRules[%] // KeyTake[y]
```

> <|y -> 0|>

Answer (score 0):

One possible way. In the second example, ommit this variable in Solve, which should remain finally.

```
asum1 = a == b && a == d;

sol1 = First@Solve[asum1]
a*b - a*d /. sol1
(*   0   *)

asum2 = w == 0 && a == b && a == d;

sol11 = Solve[asum2]
{a*b - a*d, a*b*d, r*s*w + b*s} /. sol11
(*   {{0, d^3, d s}}   *)

sol12 = Solve[asum2, {b, d, w}]
{a*b - a*d, a*b*d, r*s*w + b*s} /. sol12
(*   {{0, a^3, a s}}   *)

sol13 = Solve[asum2, {a, b, w}]
{a*b - a*d, a*b*d, r*s*w + b*s} /. sol13
(*   {{0, d^3, d s}}   *)

sol14 = Solve[asum2, {a, d, w}]
{a*b - a*d, a*b*d, r*s*w + b*s} /. sol14
(*   {{0, b^3, b s}}   *)
```